# Can anybody explain why im getting this error message 'Missing ; after for-loop initialiser'

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

So I'm fairly confident the code I'm using is correct or at least this error shouldn't be happening. The issue I think is due to me using javascript code in google app script.

I've tried placing; as requested where it wouldn't break the code but it won't accept that.

```
function unique(rangeArray) {
    var result = [];

    for (var str of rangeArray); {// This is the line that is having issues
        if (!result.includes(str)) {
            result.push(str)
        }
    }

    return result;

    var strings = result

    Logger.log( unique(strings) ); 
}
```

So what I'm trying to do is get an array/range (rangeArray), go through each item in the array and if it doesn't already exist in there then push it into it. I then want to log the results to see what I get. Hopefully, this will end up with me getting all the unique items from that range/array.

Comment: You have an extra `;` that probably shouldn't be there but that code doesn't seem to be  *missing* stuff

Comment: also it looks like var strings = result should have a ; after it

Comment: @VLAZ although I see it is returning before that line, so it never runs anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Apps Script does not support ES6 (and so does not understand `for..of` or `.includes`). Use `filter` instead:

```
function unique(rangeArray) {
  return rangeArray.filter(function(str, i) {
    return rangeArray.indexOf(str) === i;
  });
}
```

Or, for less time complexity, use an object to check to see if the string has been used yet:

```
function unique(rangeArray) {
  const strs = {};
  return rangeArray.filter(function(str, i) {
    if (strs.hasOwnProperty(str)) {
      return;
    }
    strs[str] = true;
    return true;
  });
}
```

For the more general case, if you do like using ES6+ syntax but your environment doesn't support it, you may write code in the latest version of the language and then *automatically* transpile it down to ES5 with a tool like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/repl/). (though transpiling `for..of` will require RegeneratorRuntime, which is somewhat heavyweight...)

Comment: Thank you for your response.

I've tried your code & it is returning this error on the filter line:
''TypeError: Cannot call method "filter" of undefined. ''
Do you know why this might be?

Comment: It means that you didn't pass anything to `unique`, because the first argument is undefined. Pass an array instead.

Comment: So im using the second block of code now and its not returning any errors - but its also not returning what I need. 

I may have phrased my question badly upon further review. The range is from a spreadsheet (the range etc is sorted already dont need help with that) I need to go through each item in the array and check if it exists anywhere else in the array. I then need only the unique items in a new array. Thanks for you help so far I am really new to this! (As you can probably tell)

Comment: The code as is in your question has the `var strings` and `Logger.log` going unused, because they're after the `return`.